# Ruby String Partition

Tags: ruby, string, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string into a list, but keeping the split pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957858/split-string-into-a-list-but-keeping-the-split-pattern)

```
"hello world, I am the universe".partition(/I am/)
    #=> ["hello world, ", "I am", " the universe"]
```

What is the ruby way of having this output? Please keep in mind of more complex strings as well.

```
#=> ["hello world, ", "I am the universe"]
```

Complex:

```
"hello world, I am the universe, I am the world".some_partitioning_function(/I am/)
#=>["hello world, ", "I am the universe, ", "I am the world"]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "partition"?

Comment: Can you please expand on your question, especially the "more complex strings" part?  It would help to see more examples, each with both the input string and the expected output array.

Comment: Added a more of a complicated example.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate :). `"hello world, I am the universe".partition(/I am/).each_slice(2).map(&:join)` =! `["hello world, ", "I am the universe"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method not there? Add your own:

```
class String
  def some_partitioning_function(delim_str)
    split(delim_str).map.with_index do |str, i|
      i > 0 ? delim_str + str : str
    end
  end
end

"hello world, I am the universe, I am the world".some_partitioning_function('I am')

 => ["hello world, ", "I am the universe, ", "I am the world"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"hello world, I am the universe".split(/,\s(?=I\sam)/,2)
```

Is it really what you were looking for?

Comment: Already tried it: `["hello world, ", " the universe"]`

Comment: I've made 4 attempts, none of them were what you're looking for. I will just give up now, not my day.

Comment: @Anton, There's another example in the question now, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You said it wasn't a duplicate of [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957858/split-string-into-a-list-but-keeping-the-split-pattern) @pwned linked to but it kind of is. You just need to fiddle with the Ruby a little.

```
s = "hello world, I am the universe, I am the world" # original string
a = s.split(/(I am)/) 
#=> ["hello world, ", "I am", " the universe, ", "I am, " the world"]
```

Now we will use the solution suggested in the above linked SO question. Except we will skip the first element of the array.

```
sliced = a[1..-1].each_slice(2).map(&:join) 
#=> ["I am the universe, ", "I am the world"]
```

Now we combine that with the array element we left out.

```
final = [a[0]] + sliced 
#=> ["hello world, ", "I am the universe, ", "I am the world"]
```

Throw this into a method like:

```
class String
  def split_and_include(words)
    s = self.split(/(#{words})/)
    [s[0]] + s[1..-1].each_slice(2).map(&:join)
  end
end 

"You all everybody. You all everybody.".split_and_include("all")
#=> ["You ", "all everybody. You ", "all everybody."]
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner way of doing this and I will update the answer upon discovering an easier method.

Answer (score 0):

I think this task should be resolved by regex, my regex is not so neat, maybe you can fix it later on.

```
reg = /(.+?(?=I\sam))(I\sam.+?(?=I\sam)|I\sam.+$)/
str = "hello world, I am the universe, I am the world, I am the earth"

str.scan(reg).flatten
=> ["hello world, ", "I am the universe, ", "I am the world, ", "I am the earth"]
```