# Parsing dates in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to parse some dates with bad formatting in Ruby. I decided to hinge part of the method on the presence of `am` or `pm`, so I've split the string there.

```
def bad_date(date)
  if date.match(/m\d/i)
    date_time = date.split('m', 2).reverse
    time = date_time.include?('m')
    date = date_time - time
  else
    date
  end
end
```

It split in the right place and reverse the array it's all good, but it takes the `m` with it. How can I replace it? Or how can I avoid that entirely?

Essentially I'm trying to convert some dates like this:

```
dates
=> ["0900am06/13/2015", "0900 am06/13/2015", "0900am 06/13/2015", "0900 am 06/13/2015"]
```

Into this:

```
2015-06-13 09:00 AM
```

With an acceptable margin of error.

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957858/split-string-into-a-list-but-keeping-the-split-pattern) has a solution for keeping the delimiter upon splitting a string. It can be repurposed to keep the `m`. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a help of [`strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) and [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) methods both :

```
require 'date'

d = Date.strptime("0900am06/13/2015", "%H%M%p%m/%d/%Y")
# => #<Date: 2015-06-13 ((2457187j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %P")
# => "2015-06-13 00:00 am"
d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p")
# => "2015-06-13 00:00 AM"
```

Here is a method:

```
require 'date'

def bad_date(date)
  DateTime.strptime(date.tr(" ",''), "%H%M%p%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p")
end

dates = ["0900am06/13/2015", "0900 am06/13/2015", "0900am 06/13/2015"]
dates.map { |d| bad_date d }
# => ["2015-06-13 09:00 AM", "2015-06-13 09:00 AM", "2015-06-13 09:00 AM"]
```

Comment: d = Date.strptime("0900am06/13/2015".gsub(/ /,''), "%H%M%p%m/%d/%Y")

Answer (score 2):

```
2.1.0 :085 > date = "0900am 06/13/2015"
 => "0900am 06/13/2015" 
2.1.0 :086 > date.gsub!(" ","")
 => "0900am06/13/2015" 
2.1.0 :087 > Date.strptime(date, "%H%M%p%m/%d/%Y")
 => Sat, 13 Jun 2015
```