# Typescript / Javascript - Split string but keeping the split pattern

Tags: javascript, string, split

Say I have a string "bbbX1cccY1dddA1Z1"

I split using regex pattern but the split pattern is gone. I want to maintain the split contents in the output

Wrong output

```
["bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
```

Needed output

```
["bbb", "X1", "ccc", "Y1", "ddd", "A1", "Z1"]
```

something similar to this question
[Split string into a list, but keeping the split pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957858/split-string-into-a-list-but-keeping-the-split-pattern)

Comment: What is your split pattern? Is it `[A-Z]1` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your separator pattern is `[A-Z]1`, you can opt for either of these options

1. Use a combined positive lookahead and lookbehind to separate strings proceeding or preceding the delimiter

   ```js
   str.split(/(?=[A-Z]1)|(?<=[A-Z]1)/)
   ```

   Note that browser lookbehind support is still [reasonably patchy](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind). Do not use if you need Sarafi support (MacOS or iOS).
2. Use a capturing group to include the separator and filter out empty values

   ```js
   str.split(/([A-Z]1)/).filter(s => s.length)
   ```

Comment: Isn't `str.split(/([A-Z]\d)/).filter(s => s)` would be better.

Comment: @decpk that's why I asked OP to clarify what their delimiter pattern is

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex here

```
/(?=[A-Z])|(?<=\d)/
```

Below regex will split the string if there is `CAPITAL LETTER ON RIGHT SIDE` OR `number on the left side`.

```js
const str = "bbbX1cccY1dddA1Z1";
const result = str.split(/(?=[A-Z])|(?<=\d)/);

console.log(result);
```

Below regex will work if there will be `CAPITAL LETTER and a number` are in combination...

```js
const str = "bbbX1cccY1dddA1Z1";
const result = str.split(/([A-Z]\d)/).filter(s => s);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If any numbers appear within the non-separator tokens, this will not work correctly